# How to "order" async methods? Example: Function B relies on Function A resolving first

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to angular/firestore/ionic. I know the following code is bad, but I'm not sure how to improve it. I tried using awaits ... then I tried "callbacks" but couldn't seem to figure it out. I'm not sure if there is an issue with it being specific to typescript, angular 8 or ionic.  Sorry if this is a duplicate question but I really need clarification if possible.

I tried following [Call multiple async methods that rely on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54798456/call-multiple-async-methods-that-rely-on-each-other) but it's in c# and I found [Running function with async method in sequential order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48976312/running-function-with-async-method-in-sequential-order) confusing to be honest.

```
 constructor(public modalController: ModalController,private crudService: CrudService, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFirestore) { 

    setTimeout( () => {this.currentUserID = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid}, 1000)

    setTimeout( () =>{
      var docRef = db.collection('users').doc(this.currentUserID);
      docRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data.payload.data()['selectedDate'])
        this.selDate = data.payload.data()['selectedDate']
      })
    }, 2000)

    setTimeout( () =>{
      var docRef = db.collection('users').doc(this.currentUserID);

      docRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data.payload.data()['selectedEx'])
        this.selEx = data.payload.data()['selectedEx']
      })
    }, 3000)


  setTimeout(() =>{
    var getSetsRef = db.collection('users').doc(this.currentUserID).collection('dates').doc(this.selDate).collection('userExercises').doc(this.selEx);
    getSetsRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.payload.data()['sets'])
      this.sets = data.payload.data()['sets']
    })
  }, 4000)


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only need to perform each of these queries once, not set up listeners to their continual changes.  If that's the case, you should be using `get()` to perform a query once instead of `snapshotChanges()`, which invokes a callback any time the results of the query changes.  `get()` returns a promise, and it should be straightforward to chain them all together or use async/await.